# Can't display google map using API 2

Tags: java, android

i am creating a simple app that will display google map.I have generated the API key and and followed all the steps but when i run the program it closes the app by displaying the massage "unfortunately Gmap has stopped" i even followed tutorials but it has the same result so please tell me what i am missing??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="eyob.negussie.googlemaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API KEY"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

 <fragment      
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my java class is

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button showmap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
}
}
```

please please tell what am missing????

Comment: This is the error am getting
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eyob.negussie.googlemaps/eyob.negussie.googlemaps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: i still get the same error

Comment: [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28741441/624069)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change on MapFragment instead of SupportMapFragment in layout and add this block:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MapFragment mapFragment;
GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    map = mapFragment.getMap();
    if (map == null) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead of your.

```
<fragment      
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Just need to change one line

`name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` instead of `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

For more information check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28741441/624069)